# Keep in array of words just given words from another array

Tags: python, arrays

Given an array:

```
 arr = ['a','b','c','d','a','b','d','f']
```

I would like to preprocess it with some kind of dictionary:

```
 dictionary = ['a','b','c']
```

so after: `arr.preprocess(dictionary)` all items not exisiting in dictionary will be deleted, arr will be now like:

```
['a','b','c','a','b']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
arr = ['a','b','c','d','a','b','d','f']
dictionary = ['a','b','c']
arr = [x for x in arr if x in dictionary]
```

Comment: it should be `if x **in** dictionary]`

Comment: @heisenberg7584 Thanks, it was a typo :) fixed

Answer (score 2):

```
[item for item in arr if item in dictionary]
```

Answer (score 1):

Verified Solution:

```
arr = ['a','b','c','d','a','b','d','f']
dictionary = ['a','b','c']
li = []
li = [element for element in arr if element in dictionary]
print(li)
```

Cheers

Comment: You can drop the `li = []` line; it is entirely redundant.